# 'var' vs 'this' vs constructor-parameter variables

Tags: javascript, oop

In javascript given this three constructor functions:

```
function Foo(data) {

  var _data = data;

}

function Bar(data) {

  this.data = data;

}

function Baz(data) {

   //just use data freely.

}
```

Is there any difference aside from the visibility of the `data` member after construction ? (e.g. you can do new `Bar().data` but not `new Foo().data`)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`var _data = data;` creates a local copy (not reference) of `data`.
`this.data = data` actually creates a property of the object itself.

I recommend reading this (no pun intended): http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/

Comment: Note: The local variable is assigned the value of the parameter. If the parameter is a reference to an object, the local variable will also be a reference to the same object, not a reference to a copy of the object.

Answer (score 28):

Yes, the difference is in how the variable is stored.

The variable declared with `var` is local to the constructor function. It will only survive beyond the constructor call if there is any function declared in the scope, as it then is captured in the functions closure.

The variable declared with `this.` is actually not a variable, but a property of the object, and it will survive as long as the object does, regardless of whether it's used or not.

Edit:
If you are using variables without declaring them, they will be implicitly declared in the global scope, and not part of the object. Generally you should try to limit the scope for what you declare, so that not everything end up in the global scope.

Comment: If a variable is never used... does it matter if it exists or not?

Comment: The variable will survive the constructor call even if it's not used by any method (as long as there exists at least one method). The methods do not have to use the variable - it survives because it is trapped in the scope of the method(s).

Comment: @Pablo: Not very much, but it is one effect of the difference between the ways of declaring variables.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Good point. Some languages manage to limit what's included in closures, but if what you say is correct, the closures in Javascript will contain all local variables.