# the property inside constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, this

I am new to JavaScript and currently studying constructor of class concept on Codecademy.

And my question is, what is the difference to make property between with this keyword and with let when property name is not same as the one in parameter?

I am doing some exercise on Codecademy, and when I put properties in the constructor like this, it says incorrect( but syntax error does not happen)

```
class Surgeon {
  constructor(name, department) {
    this._name = name;
    this._department = department;
    let _remainingVacationDays = 20;
  }
```

*correct answer on Codecademy

```
class Surgeon {
  constructor(name, department) {
    this._name = name;
    this._department = department;
    this._remainingVacationDays = 20;
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between using “let” and “var”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Comment: When you're using `this`, your property will be available in whole class, like in other methods. With `let` your property will be only available in current scope, you can't access them in other methods of your class.

Comment: ['var' vs 'this' vs constructor-parameter variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354418)

Comment: @SarsaMurmu — Instance, not class.

Comment: @Quentin Oh, My bad.

Comment: Thanks guys! I will through the related questions. :)